# how to get video file directory in video player in android studio

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio

This is what I do,

```
public video() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate( R.layout.fragment_video, container, false );
    recyclerView = view.findViewById( R.id.recyvle );

    videomodelArrayList = new ArrayList<>();


    runtimepermision();


    return view;
}

private void ini() {
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager( getContext());
//    GridLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager( getContext() ,2);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize( true );

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager( linearLayoutManager );

    fachfromgalary();
}

private void fachfromgalary() {

    Uri uri;
    Cursor cursor;
    int coli_int_data, columb_index_filder_name, columb_id, thum;
    String absilutpathimage = null;
    uri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    String[] projecter = {
            MediaStore.Video.Media._ID,MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA,

           MediaStore.Video.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER,

            MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.DATA};
    String orderby = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN;
    String selection= MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA+"like?";
    String []aray= new String[]{"%FolderName%"};
    cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query( uri, projecter, selection, aray, orderby + " DESC" );
    coli_int_data = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow( MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA );

   //   columb_index_filder_name = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow( MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME );
    //         columb_id=cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow( MediaStore.Video.Media._ID );
    thum = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow( MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.DATA );

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        absilutpathimage = cursor.getString( coli_int_data );
        videomodel videomodel = new videomodel();
        videomodel.setBoolean_selected( false );
     //   videomodel.setStr_name( columb_index_filder_name );
        videomodel.setStr_path( absilutpathimage );
        videomodel.setStr_thumb( cursor.getString( thum ) );
        videomodelArrayList.add( videomodel );
    }

    videoadapter videoadapter = new videoadapter( getActivity().getApplicationContext(), videomodelArrayList,getActivity() );
    recyclerView.setAdapter( videoadapter );
}

private void runtimepermision() {
    Dexter.withActivity( getActivity() ).withPermission( Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE ).withListener( new PermissionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse response) {
            ini();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse response) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permission, PermissionToken token) {
            token.continuePermissionRequest();
        }


    } ).check();
```

**Error Log:**

> 2019-11-12 15:09:06.900 6648-6682/com.abhijeet.video E/MemoryLeakMonitorManager: MemoryLeakMonitor.jar is not exist!
>   2019-11-12 15:09:06.901 6648-6648/com.abhijeet.video E/Minikin: Could not get cmap table size!
>   2019-11-12 15:09:12.444 6648-6699/com.abhijeet.video E/vndksupport: Could not load vendor/lib64/egl/libGLES_mali.so from sphal namespace: dlopen failed: library "vendor/lib64/egl/libGLES_mali.so" not found.
>   2019-11-12 15:11:53.515 6648-6648/com.abhijeet.video E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.abhijeet.video, PID: 6648
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.abhijeet.video/com.abhijeet.video.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "?": syntax error (Sqlite code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _data, _display_name, _id, _data FROM video WHERE (_datalike?) ORDER BY datetaken DESC, (OS error - 2:No such file or directory)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3303)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3411)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:5477)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19(Unknown Source:0)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2000)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7529)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
>        Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "?": syntax error (Sqlite code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _data, _display_name, _id, _data FROM video WHERE (_datalike?) ORDER BY datetaken DESC, (OS error - 2:No such file or directory)
>           at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:179)
>           at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
>           at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:418)
>           at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:766)
>           at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:716)
>           at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:667)
>           at com.abhijeet.video.fragenment_vidoe.video.fachfromgalary(video.java:97)
>           at com.abhijeet.video.fragenment_vidoe.video.ini(video.java:78)
>           at com.abhijeet.video.fragenment_vidoe.video.access$000(video.java:46)
>           at com.abhijeet.video.fragenment_vidoe.video$1.onPermissionGranted(video.java:123)
>           at com.karumi.dexter.MultiplePermissionsListenerToPermissionListenerAdapter.onPermissionsChecked(Unknown Source:35)
>           at com.karumi.dexter.DexterInstance$1.run(Unknown Source:43)
>           at com.karumi.dexter.MainThread.execute(Unknown Source:6)
>           at com.karumi.dexter.DexterInstance.checkMultiplePermissions(Unknown Source:56)
>           at com.karumi.dexter.DexterInstance.checkPermissions(Unknown Source:0)
>           at com.karumi.dexter.Dexter.check(Unknown Source:10)
>           at com.abhijeet.video.fragenment_vidoe.video.runtimepermision(video.java:137)
>           at com.abhijeet.video.fragenment_vidoe.video.onCreateView(video.java:65)
>           at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2439)
>           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1460)
>           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
>           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
>           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3269)
>           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3229)
>           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:201)
>           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:620)
>           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:178)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1339)
>           at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7403)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3266)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3411) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:5477) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19(Unknown Source:0) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2000) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7529) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)

Comment: Please share the question properly and let us know where you are facing the problem .

Comment: I want to show the folders of video file not directly video in the video player so how could I get the video folders and inside the video folder the video files

Answer (score 1):

For a start, i think you need to add a space in "like?" to " like?"

```
String selection= MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA+"like?";
```

like so

```
String selection= MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA+" like?";
```